# "This product is not compatible with macOS 10.15 Catalina" message on older macOS

Tags: steam, macos

I have macOS Sierra 10.12.6, but I keep seeing "This product is not compatible with macOS 10.15 Catalina." message instead of the "buy" button on Steam.
Is there any know solution to this?

*Can't really google this problem, google just throws at me articles about macOS Catalina and compatibility lists.*

Comment: greg-449, exactly, but why i can't play it on macOS Sierra?

Comment: The publisher may have retracted the game from further sales to avoid issues.  This is what for instance Aspyr did.  https://support.aspyr.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000214186-MacOS-Catalina-64-bit-32-bit-and-related-Questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this work around:

- Open a browser and login into your steam account there.
- Find the game, and press the play button there [this is free-to-play game in my case].
- Confirm that you already have steam installed.

the game will start to download.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download the Steam mobile app and install from there. But if you are running macOS Catalina, you can't run any more 32-bit apps unless you can copy 32-bit libraries from Mojave to Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Catalina doesn't support 32-bit applications at all. You see this warning because the game has only 32 bit version and you won't be able to play it after update (and macOS encourages you to update it).

This is support article from [Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1055-ISJM-8568), they put these as possible workarounds:

> Options to keep 32-bit Mac games playable on a Mac computer:
>
> - Consider not upgrading to macOS 10.15 or above. By staying on macOS 10.14 Mojave or older you will ensure that your 32-bit apps are still playable on your Mac computer.
> - After upgrading to macOS 10.15 Catalina, consider installing macOS 10.14 Mojave on a separate APFS volume on your computer along with Steam. This will allow you to flip over to macOS 10.14 on restart of your computer where you can continue to play all of your 32-bit Mac games. More information here.
> - Use Bootcamp on Mac to launch your games in Windows on your Mac computer. More information about Bootcamp can be found here.

Comment: From what I understand, the question isn't about upgrading to Catalina, it's about not being able to buy games on Steam, because Steam doesn't detect the OS properly.

Comment: I think this is a great answer. It explains why you can't play the games and what you can do as a work around.